# Send POST via Qt shrink the post content

Tags: php, c++, qt, post

I've created a feedback reporter which send some informations to a server.

Here's the sender part :

```
QUrl url;
url.setUrl("http://myprettyURL/server.php");

QNetworkRequest request(url);
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

QByteArray content = "Some very long content (60Ko)";

manager->post(request, content);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onSyncRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

And here's the server part :

```
$i = 0
foreach($_POST as $post){
    file_put_contents( $submission_dir . "/log" . $i ,  $post);
    $i++;
}
```

The sender send 60Ko of text (a lot of text, but not heavy data) but only 1Ko is transmitted.

Qt throw the following error :

> > qhttpnetworkrequest.cpp   static QByteArray QHttpNetworkRequestPrivate::header(const QHttpNetworkRequest &, bool) @164    content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.

So I included this line :

```
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Tested `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` `multipart/form-data` and `text/plain` but none worked.

The `post_max_size` is set to 32Mo so I don't think it's coming from here.

## Any clue of what could have shrink the content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from the sent data : I was sending chars that was interpreted as querys like `=` or `&`.

I just remove its from the string using this :

```
content.remove("[=|&]");
```

and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

All of those content types require data to be encoded before sending it! The `text/plain` content type is the simplest to use as long as you're actually sending text and not binary data.

To send plain text, you must have it in a `QString`, then encode it as `utf-8`, and finally set the content type accordingly to `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Thus:

```
QString text(QStringLiteral("foo"));
QByteArray const data = text.toUtf8();

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://myprettyURL/server.php")));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                  QStringLiteral("text/html; charset=utf-8"));
manager->post(request, data);
```